# Display "current working directory" in WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

Could someone please tell me how to display the path of the current working directory in a textbox using C# and WPF?

I don't understand how I can bind to it.

Comment: there is a plenty code you need for `binding`. You need to provide an example of **something** you already did, before we can help you with this.

Comment: What is the it you want to bind to: Directory or the TextBox.  I know you are new to SO but this question is not very clear.

Comment: would you try this sPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; and sAppPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. In ViewModel/View's code behind:

   ```
   public string CurrentDirectoryPath
   {
      get 
      { 
          return Environment.CurrentDirectory;
      }
   }
   ```
2. In View's XAML:

   ```xml
   <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentDirectoryPath}" />
   ```
3. Setup right DataContext

   ```
   // If you are using MVVM:
   var view = new MyView { DataContext = new MyViewModel() };
   ```

Comment: I am giving a +1 just for making sense of the question.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create property in window (or some other parent container):

```
public string CurrentPath
{
    get
    {
        return Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    }
}
```

And bind in XAML like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=CurrentPath, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like

```
public string CurrentPath 
{     
    get     
    { 
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;     
    } 
}
```